# Checking to see the char equivalent of my int value

Tags: c#, char, int

Okay i might not have explained it to the best of my ability but i'm a beginner and i would like to make  a piece of code that does this :
you have a string and you need to find each vowel in it and multiply each vowel's position in the string by its position in the alphabet and add all the sums together
example : steve: has 2 vowels the first e's position is 3 and its position in the alphabet is 5. and the second's position in the alphabet and the string is 5 
so the sum is 5*3 + 5*5 = 40
this is what i did . idk what to do now or how to approach it

```
 var vowels = new char[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y', 'A','E','I', 'O', 'U','Y'};
        var chars = new List<char>();
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Write something : ");
        var input =  Console.ReadLine();

        int index;
        foreach (var vowel in vowels)
        {
            if (input.Contains(vowel))
            {
                index = input.IndexOf(vowel);
                indexes.Add(index + 1);
                chars.Add(vowel);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you think of the first character in `input` as position 1 or position 0?

Comment: ik that it should be 0 but the exercise specified that it has to be 1 @mjwills

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this (Reference is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109890/c-sharp-count-vowels)):

```
    var vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    Console.WriteLine("Write something : ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    int total = 0;
    for (int temp = 1; temp <= input.Length; temp++)
    {
        if (vowels.Contains(input[temp - 1]))
        {
            total += temp * (char.ToUpper(input[temp -1]) - 64);
        }
     }

     Console.WriteLine("The length is " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Whatever
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var vowels = new Dictionary<string, int>(5, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { { "a", 1 }, { "e", 5 }, { "i", 9 }, { "o", 15 }, { "u", 21 } };

            Console.WriteLine("Write something : ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            var sum = input.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .Sum(x =>
                    {
                        vowels.TryGetValue(x.value.ToString(), out var multiplier);
                        return (x.index + 1) * multiplier;
                    });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Select` projects the original string as an anonymous type with the `char` and its index included.

The `Sum` checks if the string is a vowel - and if it is it multiplies the position (`index + 1`) by the position in the alphabet (from `vowels`).

`vowels` is case insensitive so that "A" and "a" are treated the same.

*If the compiler complains about the `out var` then use:*

```
int multiplier = 0;
vowels.TryGetValue(x.value.ToString(), out multiplier);
return (x.index + 1) * multiplier;
```

*instead.*

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out right here

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
        {
            sumofone += indexes[i] * (char.ToUpper(chars[i]) - 64);
        }
```

Comment: Consider doing this logic **inside** of your `if` statement to avoid the need for `indexes` and `chars`. Similar to @Gauravsa's approach.