# Better solution to write out cases

Tags: c#, .net

My program counts vowels and consonants from an entered string of text. Is there a way to make my cases more simplified and look less like a cluster? Just wondering if there is a better way to write them out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replace the photos with the code.

Comment: hi Kadex, you can reduce the number of lines by checking only for AEIOU for vowels and put else consonants

Comment: There is a culture-dependent aspect of a character being a "vowel" or a "consonant". I suppose your task is to classify English text, but this should be stated explicitely.

Comment: Also dupe of [Counting vowel and consonant in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18109890/215552)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have one method which checks if `char` is *letter*, you could check if `current` char is `vowel` or `consonant` using `Contains` method.

With this method, you can find out the *counts* for both `vowels` and `consonants` using a `ternary` *operator*.

```
if(char.IsLetter(ch)){
   "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(ch) ? vowelCount++ : consonantCount++;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more idiomatic to use `Contains` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try use regex

```
var s = "Test, One two three";

Regex r = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]");
MatchCollection m = r.Matches(s);
Regex rv = new Regex("[aeiouAEIOU]");
MatchCollection mv = rv.Matches(s);

var vowels = mv.Count;
var consonants = m.Count - mv.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to punch me in the face but here you go with bitmask

```
string str = "Test. One two three.";

//               zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba      ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
long bitmask = 0b0000010000010000010001000100000000000100000100000100010001;

int vowels = 0, consonants = 0;

foreach (var ch in str)
{
    if(char.IsLetter(ch))
    {
        int shift = ch - 'A';
        if (((bitmask >> shift) & 1) == 1) vowels++;
        else consonants++;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Vowels: " + vowels);
Console.WriteLine("Consonants: " + consonants);
```

or you could use this magic number for bitmask `4575140898685201`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet which gives you the desired output.

```
        string text = "This is a Demo Content";
        text = text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
        char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','A','E','I','O','U' };
        var vowelsCount = text.Count(x => vowels.Contains(x));
        var consonantCount = text.Count(x => !vowels.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Replace the regex to this code: `text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^a-zA-Z]+", "");`. [0-9] are digits that are not letters and you can replace to empty string in the regex replace no need of second replace